# Generate computer directory using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, directory-structure, cfdirectory

I would like to display a computer's root directory using ColdFusion. By that I mean

- C:/
- D:/
- MyDocument
- etc...

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
First of all thanks to everybody that responded. I just give some more clarification about my question. I want display my computer's root directory. Suppose I have some documents to save in my PC. I don't know where I save that doc. In a CF page I want to display

- C:/
- D:/
- E:/

I want to display the above directory names dynamically generated through Java or CF.
I think now my question is clear to everybody. Thanks to all.

Comment: you need to clarify your question based on your below comments, so that if there is a 'way' someone will properly be able to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cfdirectory`](http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=cfdirectory#cfdirectory).

For example:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:/" name="DirectoryQuery" />

<cfdump var=#DirectoryQuery# />
```

That will dump a list of the directories and files in the server's C drive, and acts like a standard database query.

To get multiple directories into the same query variable, you can get two lists and a "Query of Queries" to merge them:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:/" name="FirstDirQuery" />
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="D:/" name="SecondDirQuery" />

<cfquery name="DirectoryQuery" dbtype="Query">
    SELECT * FROM FirstDirQuery
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM SecondDirQuery
</cfquery>

<cfdump var=#DirectoryQuery# />
```

Comment: thanks for replay Peter...Actually i want to display computers root directory means c,d,e etc

Comment: Actually i want to display computers root directory means c,d,e etc

Comment: If you want to do multiple directories, you need to do multiple cfdirectory tags. You can then use a Query of Query to combine them.

Comment: And if you want to display the local user's files, you can't do that with ColdFusion, since it runs on the server.

Comment: yes, actually i want to do dispaly  local user's files. once again thanks for the replay

Comment: For that, you need to find a Flash widget or Java applet which can do the listing then send the appropriate info back to the server. Also, it's well worth reading up on how client/server HTTP requests work - there are important "boundaries" which aren't always obvious in today's "ajaxified" world, but that dictate how things need to be done.

Comment: Here you spacefy about two directorie namely C & D. Then my question is that how we know that there is only two directory? if there is more than 2 directory namely "K" then how I'll get that directory name.. CAn you help me

Comment: @csd - Did you see Peter's response? CF cannot provide a listing of files on the user's computer. So the answer to your question depends on what tool you end up using for that task: Flash, java applet, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Below code may help you

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#ExpandPath('.')#" name="myFiles">

<cfform name="myform" action="" method="post">
    <cftree name="dirBrowse">
        <cftreeitem query="myFiles" value="name">
    </cftree>
</cfform>
```

You can find detailed answer at below link:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=691047

Comment: Just curious, any reason you must use an applet? When that link was posted in 2003, java applets were probably the only option. But cftree supports [html/javascript format](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d84.html) now. Plus there are a bunch javascript/jquery tree widgets available. Just do a search.

Comment: I agree with you @Leigh. CFTree supports now `flash`, `object` and `xml` along with applet. But still, attributes like `LookAndFeel`, `img` work with only applets.  
I have found an interesting link at adobe's website  [Click here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a86.html)

Comment: True, not all of the attributes are consistent. You can tweak the css settings manually through the underlying library, but not as simply. That said, html trees tend to have a broader compatibility base than applets or flash format, since the only requirement is javascript.